# In FME I want to copy all the styles from a dataset but not the geometry or attributes

Tags: mapinfo, fme-form

I tried reading it in and exposing all the format attributes and then I connected it to the writer that does the last step of a larger process. It copies the formatting across but also the features. I also tried to put the styler in between.

How can I just get all the styles to use without having to use Mapinfo styler and defining all the styles manually?

Does FME have something like https://github.com/NathanW2/MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator but to go from one mapinfo tab file to another?

Can it also copy hotlink settings?

[image]

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to read all the styles within a TAB file and apply them to another TAB file? But you don't want to copy across the features? As @markireland stated, you cannot write empty features. However, perhaps you could run a python shutdown script or pythoncaller transformer which executes a mapbasic script which deletes all rows in the table after. Seems roundabout, but should work.

Comment: I don't want to delete all the rows in the table - I just want it to have the same symbology as the input. I'll un-accept the answer and ask this slightly differently with what I have tried.

Comment: Why not just use the MapInfo Styler and assign the format attribute from the incoming data?

Comment: The incoming data doesn't have the formatting -it's in a separate file. Is there a way to capture the different styles that are in a dataset?

Comment: Well, that should be possible. So, for example, fill styles, pen styles, hatching, etc? You just want a list of all styles that are in a file? I think this is definitely doable. Then what? Write them to a text file? Or you want to write them to your new file? Have you tried a feature merger? Just merge attributes and not geometry. Only merge the format attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, FME won't do this. You can remove the geometry with a GeometryRemover transformer, you can remove attributes by deleting them from the output schema, and you can reduce the number of features to 1 using a Sampler; but you can't write a completely empty dataset. If no features are provided to the writer, then no files are written.

So if you write a single, minimal feature then any styling should be carried across, but you can't get an empty TAB file with styling, to my knowledge.

Hotlinks I'm not sure about. I think it should copy those. Also (if we're talking about the same thing) you can set them with an AttributeCreator transformer by creating attributes like this:

[image]